# How to drag an 3d object with another 3d object using script in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, unityscript

I want to drag 3D object with using another 3D object on collision. can anybody help me

Answer (score 0):

I´m assuming that by "drag" you mean an object that follows other object under certain conditions.

You should use Vector3.MoveTowards() witch will move an object toward a target.

```
// The target marker.
var target: Transform;

// Speed in units per sec.
var speed: float;


function Update () {
    // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
    var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
}
```

From unity documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html